# Having trouble with SQL query in jaspersoft database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am an intern who is a complete newbie at `jaspersoft` and SQL, and am trying to make a report that returns IP Address; Username; number of logins from this IP; number of logins overall; date user created; last login date; product line. The condition is that the report should only return IP addresses that have multiple users logged in from them in the given timeframe.

I am having trouble with a lot of the code, as this is my first time writing SQL. So far, I have:

```
SELECT user_logins.ip_address,
users.id, users.login, users_logins.ip_logins,
users_logins.overall_logins, user_logins.logged_in_at, user_logins.logged_out_at,
user_logins.product_line
FROM user_logins
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = user_logins.user_id
    WHERE user_logins.logged_in_at BETWEEN ($P{start_date}::timestamp AT TIME ZONE $P{time_zone}) AND ($P{end_date}::timestamp AT TIME ZONE $P{time_zone})
    AND ($P{include_phs} OR users.email IS NULL OR users.email !~* '@prevailhs(-test)?.com')
    ORDER BY user_logins.logged_in_at DESC
```

I know that for the conditional statement, I will have to do something like `count(users_logged_in)>1`

Any insight would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: You are missing a few commas in your `SELECT` statement. You need one after `user_logins.ip_address` and after `users_logins.ip_logins`.

Comment: fixed commas, what else am I missing?